# Prison Architect, are prisoners supposed to go outside of their cell to do things?

Tags: prison-architect

I've been playing Prison Architect for a while now, I have all the rooms, and everything set. However, my prisoners don't go outside of their cell, even at feeding time. I don't know if they're supposed to do stuff like leave their cell, but they're also starving for some reason and I don't know what to do.

Here's a picture of the prison:

[image: A prison]

Comment: Could you make a picture at day? It is nearly impossible to see the edges.

Comment: Also a screenshot in deployment mode would be really helpful!  You can always [edit] your own posts

Answer (score 3):

go to your deployment, is your prison blinking yellow?

The prisoners should be able to leave their cells to go to certain rooms such as the yard and to get food etc...

Usually it won't class your prisoners as uncuffed in case they believe there is something wrong with the prison.

My thoughts also come down to the cells needing to be connected to a hallway which attaches to each other room/building as they need to have certain paths allocated to staff/prisoners/High Warning Prisoners.

Look at what areas are marked as. i had this problem because one of my main hallways was marked Medium only so my high risk guys would do nothing else. had to switch back to shared. worked fine after that.

Example here: [image: http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/233450/ss_0c13ec061d922fbe8ad518eb58487cff09d3fd40.600x338.jpg?t=1460365567]

There you can see paths connected to each cell and the locations they can go to.

Comment: Here's a picture of my prison, by the way I have unlimited spending on http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/442858682655055530/F6849DD1E5D17553699700DB9EDF03ED2EFB8292/

Answer (score 1):

I see your kitchen equipment is smashed together in the same room as the Canteen, but I don't see a separate zone in there actually designating any space as a Kitchen.

If you have no Kitchens zoned, it doesn't matter if mealtime is scheduled, no one will go work in one.  Cookers don't do anything unless they are in a kitchen and get worked, so as far as I can see, nothing gets cooked, nothing gets served, and nobody eats.

Comment: It also could be because your perimeter isn't closed in and therefore no guards will let them outside, or if you have no actual valid workers to work in the kitchen, or if you don't have mealtimes on your schedule.... all of which I wouldn't actually be able to see in your screenshot, so this is just my guess trying to eyeball this one piece of info.